# PostgreSQL unable to parse string to date using to_date()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty standard date as a string that I need to parse to a date type:

```
"2016-06-01T23:34:25+00:00"
```

I'm using `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS'` as the format mask and this query to try to get and parse the date:

```
SELECT to_date('last_updated_on', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS') 
AS last_updated_on FROM locations 
limit 1
```

What happens is I get this error:

```
ERROR: invalid value ":2" for "MI"
SQL state: 22007
Detail: Value must be an integer.
```

I've looked all over in the documentation and on SO trying to find out why this is happening, and I'm totally baffled.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surround the `T` in format string with `""`. If the time part of the date needs to be preserved, use `to_timestamp()`.

```
SELECT to_date('last_updated_on', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') 
AS last_updated_on FROM locations 
limit 1
```

Converting to date with timestamp

```
SELECT to_timestamp('last_updated_on', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') 
AS last_updated_on FROM locations 
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that `T` was the culprit, but didn't know how to define it as a literal "T"

Answer (score 4):

The problem would appear to be the `T` n the middle of the string.  This seems tow work:

```
SELECT to_date(replace('2016-06-01T23:34:25+00:00', 'T', ''),  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

However, you probably want `to_timestamp()`:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('2016-06-01T23:34:25+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Also note that you have single quotes around `last_updated_on`.  That means that it is interpreted as a string, not a column name.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Yeah I put that `last_updated_on` in when writing my question. The value that goes in there comes from a jsonb value, which I took out to try to clarify the meaning of the question.